# How to make this Code work GUI Textbox to textbutton?

Tags: user-interface, lua, scripting

Ok so here's what I want to know.

I am making a GUI for roblox and I want too know how to make this button 
interact with this textbox so what ever value is in the text box thats what will change when you hit the button

Here's the code to change the values

```
v.leaderstats1.Level.RobloxLocked =  true
v.leaderstats1.Level.Value = 98000
```

And heres the code for the mousebutton click

```
LevelButton.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
end)
```

So how do I combine this into 1 code so I can type a " value " like (3799)
and hit the button and it works?

any my text box is LevelBox.Name

Comment: Trying something out, will write back if it works

Comment: Update: It worked I just did this :D

v.leaderstats1.Level.Value = LevelBox.Text